# What does getItemHtml() function mean in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

What does this line basically mean in the code?

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($itemStartLv, true, $id); ?>
```

I have searched for this but no clear explanations out there or maybe someone can explain it more clear here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($itemStartLv, true, $id); ?>
```

basically, there are no any meaning of it.

This is the function which is defined in your block.

you can check releted block and see function defined in block file for get HTML of perticular item.

hope now its clear.

fell free to ask if you have any query :)